# Valuable Riverpod usage between Widgets

Tags: flutter, state, provider, riverpod, sharing

I‘m looking for a valuable solution
for the following Flutter Riverpod provider

My repo has a
Flutter_map page
In this page I have multiple layers

- custom location marker layer
- polygon layer
- map Control Button Layer
- Marker Layer

To avoid permanent reloads of complete Fluttermap page I need a clean solution to share the state of between two layers

- the marker button layer for example should share a state of bearing / map alignment to custom location layer.

The approach was a notifier Provider in Map Control button layer which sets a state mapalign.always or mapalign.never

Problem is: the state of this provider in map Control Button Layer is not the same state in equal (global) named alignment provider  in custom location marker layer. This is correct by documentation, but I need to exchange the state between multiple Widgets.

Has anyone a useful hint.

No solution is a ref.watch(alignprovider) in flutter_map parent widget and rebuild the entire Widget tree.

No solution is a ref.watch(alignprovider) in flutter_map parent widget and rebuild the entire Widget tree.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.